# Code to sort information into table from excel to access?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I currently have an excel datasheet with an address field that has the full address printed on it (Street, Province, Country, Postal) and in access I have each category separated into different columns. Would I be able to input this data automatically into the table? If not, I have about a thousand lines to do, it'll take me forever to copy/paste the data!

The excel table looks like this:

```
1234 Free Road, Toronto, On, L4Z6B1
1444 Long Street, Chilliwack, Bc, V2R9E1
99 Princible Street, Travadie, Nb
```

As you can see, some don't have postal codes. Some do. Also (not shown here) some are from America, so they have zip codes which look different.

The access table looks like this:
[image: Access table]

Comment: Have you tried using the [Text to Columns](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261) feature in Excel?

Comment: Have you tried using the Get External Data feature in Access?

Comment: I've tried external data, but the text to columns works! Gord, if you would like to make that the answer I'll gladly mark it as the answer and up vote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way to split up that data would be to use the "Text to Columns" feature in Excel:

[How to parse data using the Text To Columns command in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261)